# Which Part to integrate with FCM? Frontend or Backend

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native

So let's jump on the direct issue. I've made a native app where I'm using laravel REST API as backend and reactjs as frontend. I have completed all the functionality except Push Notifications.

- Now I don't know how fcm works and which part I'd have to integrate?
  If I have to integrate laravel or reactjs and how do I do that?

I hope you guys get my question and please pardon me if my question is silly. I'm a beginner so I hope you understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FCM` directly into any `laravel` project by using packages. 
There is package exists in laravel to make it easy . 
Take a look at it .

[Laravel-FCM-package](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the code to receive notification in Your Frontend (ReactJs or React native). The notification will be pushed from the FCM Server, have a look at the documentation to know [How it works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging#how_does_it_work)?

Or, you can simply follow this medium article: [Implementing FCM in React Native](https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591)

Also, if this is a web app then follow this article: [FCM Integration in ReactJS](https://codeburst.io/how-to-add-push-notifications-on-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-react-web-app-de7c6f04c920)

Comment: Okay, I have to integrate it with reactjs but another question is do I have to integrate it with laravel also?

Comment: if you want to send notification by logging into the console then no need for that but if you have a backend where a person will create notification then you'll have to integrate it with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my last task. So u have to use Laravel or backend engine to send firebase cloud message (fcm) and using reactjs to retrieve it.

For backend based on php (Laravel/lumen/whatever) you can use this : 
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud-messaging.html

or if you need more simple, just using curl() function. This is my simple function for fcm :

```
public function sendCloudMessageTopic($title, $message, $topics, $detail = null)
    {
        try {

            $serverApiKey = "YOUR APP FIREBASE KEY";
            $header       = [
                "Authorization: Key=" . $serverApiKey,
                "Content-Type: Application/json",
            ];

            $notification = [
                "title" => $title,
                "body" => $message,
            ];

            $data = [
                "notification" => $notification,
                "detail" => $detail,
            ];

            $payload = ["notification" => $notification, "data" => $data, "to" => $topics];
            $curl    = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $failed   = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            if ($failed == TRUE)
                throw new \Exception("CURL Action Failed to send firebase cloud message");

            $result = json_decode($response);

            if (!isset($result->message_id))
                throw new \Exception("Failed to send firebase cloud message");

            return [
                'status' => 1,
                'message' => "successfully sending firebase cloud message"
            ];

        } catch
        (\Exception $exception) {
            return [
                'status' => 0,
                'message' => "Failed to send firebase cloud message"
            ];
        }
    }
```

I've never tried it for fronted to retrieve it, but you can take a look to this article :

https://codeburst.io/how-to-add-push-notifications-on-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-react-web-app-de7c6f04c920

Thanks,